# During your tour, you will see historic buildings.. or historical?

Tags: word-choice

In the description of a guided tour across a city, what adjective should one pick:

> During your tour, you will see **historic** buildings

or

> During your tour, you will see **historical** buildings

Judging by [this helpful explanation](http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/historic_historical.htm), one should opt for *historic* if the building is important in history, and for *historical* if the building is merely part of the city's history:

> The adjective *historic* means having importance in history or having influence on history. 
>  The adjective *historical* means having taken place in history, from the past or pertaining to history.

Judging by Google, both adjectives are used, although *historic* seems to predominate. 
Which of them is more appropriate in my case?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, **historical buildings** is correct, if you are referring to old, landmark buildings that have a "history" or have been around from time historical.

Comment: And if I use *historic buildings*, would that imply that the buildings had significant impact on history beyond my city?

Comment: Potentially, yes. Although you might have to make clear why they are considered historic, what historic event(s) they hosted, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A *historic* event is an important event whereas *historical* event is the event happened in the past. The past is history and thus, the event is *historical*.

*'Historic'* means very important and likely to be remembered in coming years. Say *historic building*, the building that is likely to be remembered. On the other hand, *historical* means something already happened in the past or connected with the past (as in historical study/research).

So, in your case, the buildings are monuments and a part of tour (sightseeing). They are ***historical buildings***.

[A piece of information from OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/historic)

> Historic is usually used to describe something that is so important that it is likely to be remembered:Today is a historic occasion for our country.Historical usually describes something that is connected with the past or with the study of history, or something that really happened in the past:I have been doing some historical research. ◇ Was Robin Hood a historical figure?

To play a pun, the building that is historic today will be historical in coming decades ;)

Answer (score 0):

Longman Dictionary says

a historic place or building is very old
the restoration of historic buildings

Macmillan says

a historic place is important because it is old and interesting or impressive
the historic city of York