# Can you call it a Historical event

Tags: meaning, word-usage

can you call a meeting of world leaders that took place in 1947 a historical event?

Thanks

Comment: are you asking about the use A historical, or  AN historical?

Comment: No, I was wondering if I could call a meeting of world leaders a historical event.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [During your tour, you will see historic buildings.. or historical?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30719/during-your-tour-you-will-see-historic-buildings-or-historical)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but I suspect the term you are looking for is *historic*.

- An event that is *historic* is noteworthy.
- An event that is *historical* is simply an event in the past, ie it belongs in history.

So, everything that happened in the past is historical, but not everything is historic.

---

Also note that, in British English, some insist it should be **an** historic event (like "an honourable man").

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am talking about events from the past, so: is a meeting of world leaders that took place in 1947 AN historical event? :)

Comment: Yes, that is what the answer told you.

Comment: @Rowan Yes Rowan, *everything* that happened in the past is *historical*, but not everything is *historic*. You can call your meeting of world leaders 'historical' if you like, but I think you mean 'historic'.

Comment: @Astralbee Small nit pick, but only past events that were recorded in history are "historical." Events that occurred in prehistory (before written records began) wouldn't be called "historical," at least by a(n) historian. Still, +1 and I'll refer to your answer from the OP's duplicate post. I hadn't seen your answer at the time.

Comment: @TypeIA I'd have to disagree - the word "historical" is used in a much wider context these days. For example, we often refer to "historical reasons" for something in the present. Those details may not have been considered important at the time, but they are now recognised as such. This gets used in the workplace when referring to legacy procedures etc, so it has less to do with "history books" these days.

Comment: @Astralbee It doesn't have to be in a history book, but it has to be recorded in some way. An example of what I mean is the [asteroid impact that (probably) killed off the dinosaurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alvarez_hypothesis). This is generally accepted to have happened based on scientific evidence, but it is _not_ a historical event because it was not recorded by humans in any form of history.

Comment: @TypeIA In trying to prove that "historical" events have to be written down, you've not only gone for an example that isn't written but one that is *purely theoretical* (no matter how well supported). I put it to you that, if you can have an "oral history", then any details of the past which can be recounted, but not necessarily recorded, are "historical" without. For example: "*Historically, common law courts relied little on legal scholarship*". This does not mean that courts had written instruction to "rely on little legal scholarship", but that this has been subsequently recognised.