# Is the Statue of Liberty a historic building, a historical building or both?

Tags: word-choice

**Note:** This post is discussing a specific example, which is different to the posts that just give some general rules which might not applicable here, such as some posts that just talk about event but don't even mention a word about building.

---

Is the Statue of Liberty a historic building, a historical building or both?

I've gone through [an ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/30719/117396), which gives a general answer, that is, a historical building.

I also went through [a tutorial on English Grammar Today](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/historic-or-historical), which is informative though doesn't answer the question directly.

> Historic means ‘important or likely to be important in history’ ... Historical means ‘related to the study of things from the past’

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statue_of_Liberty#Dedication)

> The monument was expanded to also include Ellis Island in 1965. The following year, the Statue of Liberty and Ellis Island were jointly added to the National Register of **Historic** Places

Which seems to indicate that the Statue of Liberty is a historic building.

Which one should I go with?

Comment: I am not sure if "[Can you call it a Historical event](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/232275/can-you-call-it-a-historical-event)" is a duplicate. Also the difference is discussed on [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/historic-historical/).

Comment: You could easily have looked up the distinction yourself. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/historic-or-historical                      https://www.grammarly.com/blog/historic-historical/

Comment: I disagree that this is not the same as [During your tour, you will see historic buildings.. or historical?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30719/during-your-tour-you-will-see-historic-buildings-or-historical) That question is talking about buildings of exactly the same type as the Statue of Liberty, and asking which word should be used. There's also no reason why *both* words cannot be used—although it's far more common to just use *historic*, since *historical* is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I think "historic" makes more sense in this particular case.

Calling a structure "historical" suggests to my ear either that it no longer exists, or that its significance lies in the past. Although the Statue of Liberty was of course constructed in the past, it remains in the present a potent and significant symbol of liberty and freedom and of the United States.

Comment: Thank you. "Its significance lies in the past" means, "it's not as important nowadays or it no longer exists".  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @JQQ Yes, that's right. We might call Stonehenge a(n) historical site: even though part of it is still there, its only significance today is as a reminder of whatever **historical** events, ceremonies, etc. occurred there.